# Превращение строки в число php

Tags: php, строки, int

Возможно ли в php подобную строку "125/10" превратить в 12.5 без использования функции, explode?

Comment: eval(), например

Comment: Если данные приходят от пользователей, `eval` может для вас стать критичным.

Answer (score -1):

```
$str = "125/10";
$delimoe = (int)$str;
$handler = preg_match("/[0-9]*/", substr($str, strpos($str, '/') + 1), $matches);
$delitel = $matches[0];
$chastnoye = $delimoe/$delitel;
echo $delimoe . "/" . $delitel .'=' . $chastnoye;
```

125/10=12.5

Comment: Ради чего такие темные дела проворачивать? Когда `explode` решит задачу в 3, а то и 4 раза быстрее? Я так понял, по каким-то причинам, автору не устраивает `explode`, то уж ваш пример и подавно затмит ему голову. Да и вообще - это ужас написан, проще уж было через `preg_split` решить ,тоже было бы, в 2 раза быстрее.